# Python change the array's dimension from (n,1) for (n,)

Tags: arrays, numpy, spyder

If I declare an array "v" whose shape is (3,100) when I want to change its values column by column making use a "for" python changes the dimension of "v[:,i]" for (3,) this is annoying and I can't make the change because at the left member it has a (3,) array and in the right, it has an (3,1) array.

I would like to know, why does this happen? and which are my options to cope with this?

Thanks.

```
v = np.ones( (3, 100) );

for i in range( 0 , 100 ):
    
    v[:,i] = np.array([[1],
                       [2],
                       [3]])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [379]: M = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
```

Indexing with a scalar reduced the dimension by one.  That's a basic rule of indexing - in `numpy` and `python`.

```
In [380]: M[0,:]                                                                                     
Out[380]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
In [381]: M[:,0]                                                                                     
Out[381]: array([0, 4, 8])
```

Same for a list:

```
In [383]: M.tolist()                                                                                 
Out[383]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
In [384]: M.tolist()[0]                                                                              
Out[384]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Index with a list/array or slice, does preserve the dimension:

```
In [385]: M[:,[0]]                                                                                   
Out[385]: 
array([[0],
       [4],
       [8]])
```

So assigning a (3,) to the (3,) slot is fine:

```
In [386]: M[:,0] = [10,20,30]
```

Assigning a (3,1) to that slot produces an error:

```
In [387]: M[:,0] = [[10],[20],[30]]                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-387-1bbfa6dfa93c> in <module>
----> 1 M[:,0] = [[10],[20],[30]]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
In [388]: M[:,0] = np.array([[10],[20],[30]])   # or with an array                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-388-6e511ffdc44e> in <module>
----> 1 M[:,0] = np.array([[10],[20],[30]])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
```

By broadcasting (3,) can go into (1,3), but not (3,1) into (3,).  One solution is to flatten the RHS:

```
In [389]: M[:,0] = np.array([[10],[20],[30]]).ravel()
```

Assigning to a (3,1) slot also works:

```
In [390]: M[:,[0]] = np.array([[10],[20],[30]])                                                      
In [391]: M[:,0:1] = np.array([[10],[20],[30]])
```

We could also transpose the (3,1) to (1,3).  Or assign to `M[:,0][:,None]` or `M[:,0,None]` (both of which create a (3,1)).

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are asking is: how to set them column wise.

```
v = np.ones( (3,100) )

for i in range( 0 , 100 ):

    v[:,i] = np.array([1,
                       3,
                       2])
```

The change is to remove extra brackets in your assignment.

If you are trying to do something else, you can try doing it for rows, and flip array sideways:

```
v = np.ones((100,3))

for i in range(0,100):
    v[i] = np.array([1,3,2])
```

EDIT: changed the whitespace to be the same as the author

Comment: But I shouldn't change the array v, in the real code (whichI am working) v is not so simple

Comment: @VEBP did you try my first code example? It does what you are asking

Comment: @VEBP I changed the white space to match what you are trying to do. The semicolons in python are optional, and not recommended.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but the problem is solved with

v[ : , [i] ] = np.array( [ [1],[2],[3] ] )